# jquery-ui vertical navigation menu using with themeswitcher

Tags: php, jquery-ui, menu, navigation

I would like to have a vertical navigation menu compatibbel with jQuery UI ThemeRoller.
How can I define the styles for my menu?
I just build menus dynamically and php code is following:

```
$menu = '<ul>';
foreach ($items as $val) {
    if ( 'sep' == $val['link'] )
        $menu.=$val['label'].'<br>';
    else {
      //  echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']."<br>".DEF_PATH.$val['link'];

        if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] == DEF_PATH.$val['link']) {
            $menu .= '<li class="current"><a href="'.$val['link'].'"';
            $menu .= ' class="current"';
        }else
            $menu .= '<li><a href="'.$val['link'].'"';
        $menu .= ' target="'.$val['target'].'" '.'>'.$val['label']."</a></li>\n";
    }
}
$menu.="</ul>\n";
$main_menu.=$menu;
```

thanks Arman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Uses "CSS Framework", [you can read about it here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API).  Basically it uses a well defined set of classes for specific things, just use the appropriate classes include the theme/CSS you want to use and you're done :)

For a menu you probably want to start with the [Interaction States](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API#Interaction_States) classes section.  For example instead of this:

```
<li class="current">
```

You would probably want `ui-state-active` or `ui-state-highlight` either replacing or in addition to `current` (in addition if `.current` has *additional* style rules you want), like this:

```
<li class="current ui-state-active">
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. my 'current' defines the "a:hover". Can I tell my 'current' class that hover should be ui-state-hover?

Comment: @Arman - I would do something like `$('ul li').hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover'); });`, that'll apply the class to the `<li>` when hovered and remove it when it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `display:block` to them (UI might have made them inline):

```
$menu .= '<li style="display:block;"><a href="'.$val['link'].'"';
```

Comment: oh yes display block does the trick. But my hover still does not work. I should add somehow ui-state-hover:(